# Does the sencha touch store permently store to an ipad/iphone

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

Can the secha touch framework store data permanently to a iphone/ipad. So an app can update images say once a week and that storage would stay on the ipad/iphone app until prompted to clear?

Comment: Are you talking about storing the application itself or application-specific data?

Comment: Storing to the application itself over a long period of time. For example downloading magazine pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not store data permanently but you can cache the data on the users iPhone or iPad.And it will stay there until the users clears there cache.

Code like this will pull the local data on their device

```
        Ext.regStore('NotesStore', {
        model: 'Note',
        sorters: [{
            property: 'date',
            direction: 'DESC'
        }],
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'notes-app-store'
        },
        getGroupString: function (record) {
            if (record && record.data.date) {
                return record.get('date').toDateString();
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is a more in depth example with lots of comments

http://www.senchaexperts.com/api/extjs4.0/source/LocalStorage.html

Comment: By the way this is using the new local storage api available in the new HTML5 specs